Getting error while executing npm create hono@latest
While creating hono template getting this error
C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Test>npm create hono@latest
create-hono version 0.6.3
? Target directory backend
? Which template do you want to use? cloudflare-workers
- Cloning the templateC:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:17473
          throw new DegitError(`could not find commit hash for ${repo.ref}`, {
                ^

DegitError: could not find commit hash for main
    at Degit._cloneWithTar (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:17473:17)
    at async Degit.clone (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:17337:11) {
  code: 'MISSING_REF',
  ref: 'main'
}

Node.js v20.12.2
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\Desktop\Test
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-hono

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-18T16_44_34_430Z-debug-0.log

I was tring to create cloudflare worker template using npm

Verify you have git installed
